# How to use the stack in x86-64 Assembly?

Tags: assembly, stack, x86-64

I'm having a bit of trouble how to access variables in the stack. Here is what I'm doing:

```
.data
.text
input:
    .string "%ld"   #format for input
output:
    .string "%ld.\n"    #format for output

.global main
pushq   %rbp                    #push base pointer, also known as frame pointer
movq    %rsp, %rbp              #set base pointer to stack pointer, reference off of rbp for locals

subq    $8, %rsp                #allocate 16 bytes for local use
movq    $input, %rdi            #calls scanf in the format of input
movq    %rsp, %rsi
movq    $0, %rax
call    scanf


subq    $8, %rsp
movq    $input, %rdi            #calls scanf in the format of input
movq    %rsp, %rsi
movq    $0, %rax
call    scanf

movq    -8(%rsp), %rbx          #stores first number into reg rbx
movq    (%rbx),%rbx
movq    -16(%rsp), %rcx         #stores second number into reg rcx
movq    (%rcx),%rcx


movq    $output,%rdi            #prints in format input
movq    $0, %rax
movq    %rcx, %rsi
call    printf

addq $16, %rsp
popq %rbp
ret
```

I read in two integers with `scanf` and then try to store them into `rbx` and `rcx` registers. However, when I try to print one of them out, it just prints out some random integer.

Comment: One level too much indirection: `movq (%rbx), %rbx`,`movq (%rcx), %rcx` need to go away.

Comment: @EOF It still prints out a random integer.

Comment: Oh, right. You're loading from the wrong place. `movq -8($rsp), %rbx` should be `movq (%rsp), %rbx` and `movq -16(%rsp), %rcx` should be `movq 8(%rsp), %rcx`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow through your own operations on `rsp` it should be obvious that the second number is still at address `(%rsp)` since nothing has changed and the first number is at `8(%rsp)` because you have subtracted 8 from `rsp` since you have read it. Also, as @EOF said, you do not need the indirection:

```
movq    8(%rsp), %rbx        #stores first number into reg rbx
movq    (%rsp), %rcx         #stores second number into reg rcx
```

Note that calling convention mandates `rbx` to be preserved so it's a bad idea to destroy that. x86-64 has plenty of other registers to choose from ;) (But beware, some others need to be preserved too).

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick! I'll use r10 and r11 instead :)